# Excel VBA: Failed to pass a string array to a Function

Tags: vba

VBA Beginner here.

I am trying to pass an array of strings from a subroutine to a function which will then modify each string in the array. However I get the "Type:array or user-defined type expected" error message.

I have tried redefining different data types for the array so it is aligned with the data type entered in the function but to no avail.

Hope you can help! THank you so much!

Below is the dummy code:

```
Sub text()
    Dim haha() As Variant

    haha = Array("Tom", "Mary", "Adam")
    testing (haha())
    MsgBox Join(haha, " ")

End Sub

Function testing(ByRef check() As String) As String()
    Dim track As Long

    For track = LBound(check) To UBound(check)
        check(track) = check(track) & " OMG"
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Use ```Function testing(ByRef check As Variant) As String()``` and ```testing haha``` to call it.

Answer (score 1):

In orignial code, a string is not the same variant (I believe they both would need to be variant? someone can verify), you dont need the brackets after testing, only need brackets if you are setting to another value e.g.

```
haha2 = testing(haha())
```

Below code should be ok

```
Sub text()
Dim haha()
haha = Array("Tom", "Mary", "Adam")
testing haha()
MsgBox Join(haha, " ")

End Sub

Function testing(ByRef check()) As String
Dim track As Long
For track = LBound(check) To UBound(check)
    check(track) = check(track) & " OMG"
Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your code:

- There are two ways of invoking methods:

  1) with `Call` keyword - in this case you must give all the parameters in brackets:

  `Call testing(haha)`

  2) without `Call` keyword - in this case you just give your parameters after the name of function:

  `testing haha`

  In your code you combined both of them and this is syntax error.
- If you pass an array as a parameter to function you don't need to put brackets like that: `testing (haha())`.

  The proper syntax is:

  `testing(haha)`
- Function `testing` requires as a parameter an array of `String` type, you cannot pass object of other type instead since it causes compile error *Type mismatch*. Currently you are trying to pass variable `haha` which is of `Variant` type.
- You can change the type of `haha` variable to array of strings (to avoid the error described above):

  ```
  Dim haha() As String
  ```

  However, in this case you cannot assign the value of function `Array` to it, since the result of this function is of `Variant` type.
  You would have to replace this code:

  ```
  haha = Array("Tom", "Mary", "Adam")
  ```

  with this:

  ```
  ReDim haha(1 To 3)
  haha(1) = "Tom"
  haha(2) = "Mary"
  haha(3) = "Adam"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions to improve your code:

```
Dim haha() As String
```

You define the type of the entry in the array, not the array itself. Use the way mentioned by mielk to fill the array.

```
Function Testing(byref check as variant) As String
```

This will avoid problems with undefined variables. Not clear why you feel that the function should return a string though. Maybe even convert to a Sub instead.